# Office 365 App connectivity with On-Premise SQL Server Database

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365connectors

I am new to O365, need help on below scenario:

We have to deploy an office 365 app (custom app)  in our corporate Office 365 tenant. This app will communicate with SQL Server database. On-Premise database server sits in corporate virtual network . What firewall changes will be needed to enable this this connectivity?

Do we need to get all ports opened as mentioned on link https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/educloud/2011/11/30/what-firewall-ports-do-i-need-open-to-connect-to-office-365-for-education/

Answer (score 0):

The gateway creates an outbound connection to Azure Service Bus.

It communicates on outbound ports: TCP 443 (default), 5671, 5672, 9350 thru 9354.

The gateway doesn't require inbound ports.

For more information, please review the following link:
[Configure a firewall or proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/gateway-reference#configure-a-firewall-or-proxy)

Comment: Thanks @Yuki for response. We are also looking for option to migrate on-premise database server to Azure. We will be setting up MS SQL database on a Azure VM. So O365 app will need to talk to database setup on Azure VM.  In this case will data gateways still be required ? How it will impact connectivity requirement?

Comment: The gateway creates an outbound connection to Azure Service Bus. It communicates on outbound ports: TCP 443 (default), 5671, 5672, 9350 thru 9354. The gateway doesn't require inbound ports.